# getTop()/getLeft for Views in XML file in RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android

My Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
<Button  
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    ...
     />
<Button  
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"  
    ...
    />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to save the x and y positions of all buttons.

I tried this:

```
Button b[] = new Button[40];
int parX [] = new int[40];
int parY [] = new int[40];
String temp;
int resID;

for (int i=0;i<=39;i++) 
{
 temp = "id/button_" + String.valueOf(i+1);
 resID = getResources().getIdentifier("com.myapp.test:"+temp, null, null);
 b[i] = (Button) findViewById(resID);
 parX[i] = b[i].getTop();
 parY[i] = b[i].getLeft();
}
```

But b[i].getTop() and b[i].getLeft() are always 0.
But it can't be because it is correctly drawn a field of
40 buttons so they must have all different x and y positions.

How can I find out the x/y positions of the buttons of
my xml file?

Answer (score 3):

getLeft/getTop will return the correct value only after the first layout pass.

Comment: When is the first layout pass finished?  I moved getLeft/getTop to    the events onFinishInflate(), onResume(), onSizeChanged(), onLayout()  but it's always 0. In which event is the first layout passed so I can read getLeft/getTop and it's not always 0?

Comment: @user601721 look at View.getViewTreeObserver() and ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener interface. This it the callback which will be called after the layout pass.